# Is extending an existing webflowconfigurer (of the CAS webflow) feasible?

Tags: java, spring, cas

In [this](https://apereo.github.io/2018/06/19/cas53webflow-extensions/) blog post, the subject of creating a new `Webflowconfigurer` to extend the web flow is covered.

In the examples provided this is done through classes that extend the `AbstractCasWebflowConfigurer` and introducing new actions that are appended to the webflow through the included process.

Is extending already existing configurers like for instance `AcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer` and overriding some of its methods feasible or is that outside the scope of CAS web flow? If its feasible, what is the correct way to do this? 
p.s. currently on version 5.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is extending already existing configurers like for instance AcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer and overriding some of its methods feasible or is that outside the scope of CAS web flow?

Yes, that is feasible.

If you examine [this block](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/5.3.x/support/cas-server-support-aup-webflow/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/config/CasAcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfiguration.java#L71), you will find that `AcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer` is only created conditionally, if an existing bean is not already found in the context by the same name. So to provide your own, you just need to register a bean with the same name using your own `@Configuration` class. Something like this:

```java
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("defaultWebflowConfigurer")
    public CasWebflowConfigurer acceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer() {
        return new MyAcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer(...);
    }

    public class MyAcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer extends 
                          AcceptableUsagePolicyWebflowConfigurer {}
```

To learn about how `@Configuration` classes work in general, you can:

- [Review this post](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Management-Extensions.html)
- or [This post](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/21/cas-autocfg-strategy/)
- or consult the documentation for Spring and/or Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an example of extending the cas login webflow using Java for cas 6.x. I assume this can be done without having to modify the login-webflow.xml.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/webflow/Webflow-Customization-Extensions.html does not explain very well where these changes need to be made at.